# How can I create a loop video?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I made a code with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, used `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL`
and `maxRecordedDuration`.

When coming to the end of the recording file (according to `maxRecordedDuration`) the app enters `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL` with an error.

Can I make any loop when coming to `maxRecordedDuration`? overwrite part of the file?
or any sample code for video looping?

Video looping example: record for 5 minutes than record again on the same file, but not destroying (delete) the existing file.

Comment: Are you trying to play your recorded video in loops? If so, what player are you using?

Comment: I dont want to play the records in loop, I am trying to record in an endless loop.